# InlineShape.Width not working on first run

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, width

I'm trying to resize pictures in a Word document using VBA. The code works fine, but only the second time it is run. It also works if you interrupt it and then step through it. Can someone comment on what I'm missing?

```
Documents.Open FileName:=vDirectory & "\" & vFile

Dim objPic As InlineShape
For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

If objPic.Width > CentimetersToPoints(16.51) Then
    With objPic
        .Width = CentimetersToPoints(16.51)
    End With
End If

Next objPic
```

Comment: This code works fine with a test document of mine. If this is still a problem, you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: Can confirm code is working (Version: Microsoft Word 16.0, VBA 7.1). Liking the `CentimetersToPoints(double)` function

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem running a word macro from access.
(The error occured in Word as well)

I finally changed my code from:

```
Dim objWord as object
Dim pic as InlineShape
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")    
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    For Each pic In .InlineShapes
        If pic.Width > 450 Then
            pic.Width = 450
        End If
    Next
End With
```

To:

```
Dim objWord as object
Dim pic as InlineShape
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")    
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    For Each pic In .InlineShapes
        If pic.Width > 450 Then
            pic.Width = 450
        End If
    Next
    For Each pic In .InlineShapes
        If pic.Width > 450 Then
            pic.Width = 450
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Works fine. As stupid as it seems!